# Python Twitter, Message is over 140 characters for status and media_ids

Tags: python, json, twitter

I am using Python Twitter api
[Here](https://code.google.com/p/python-twitter/). The issue is when I post simple status, it works fine, but when i used `media_ids`

```
{"errors":[{"code":186,"message":"Status is over 140 characters."}]}
```

### Code

```
api.request('statuses/update', {'status': tweet, 'media_ids': media_id})
```

the length of `tweet` is 135.

Why is the error then?

Comment: Looks like it could be appending some text to the end. Any chance to get a look at the output of the api.request call?

Answer (score 2):

You need to factor in the length of the shortened URL of your media upload. The shortened URL is 23 characters, plus a single space character that separates the URL from the tweet text; so, 24 characters total. That means the most you can tweet is 116 characters.

Try doing a media upload with a short tweet. Then, download the tweet using `statuses/user_timeline`, and you will see the actual tweet with the URL.

EDIT

Using [TwitterAPI](https://github.com/geduldig/TwitterAPI)

```
from TwitterAPI import TwitterAPI
api = TwitterAPI(<CONSUMER_KEY>,<CONSUMER_SECRET>,<ACCESS_TOKEN>,<ACCESS_KEY>)
iterator = api.request('statuses/user_timeline',{'screen_name'<SCREEN_NAME>})
for item in iterator:
        if 'text' in item:
                print(item['text'])
```

Comment: I really didn't know how I can do that, probably a snippet would help me better understand this.

Comment: @Clayton I added the snippet to my answer.